# In general should routes be placed before or after middleware?

Tags: javascript, express, routes, middleware

Oddly, when I moved my middleware in front of my routes, my routes stopped working.  I got no error, on the client or the server.

My fetch() calls seemingly disappeared.

However when I put the routes before my middleware, the routes begin to work again.

I'm refactoring code and have no idea why this is happening.

```
// load middleware
const middleware = require(__dirname +'/middleware');
app.use(middleware.session.session);
...

// load routes
const routes = require(__dirname + '/routes');
app.use('/articles', routes.articles);
...
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant code for the middleware and routes? It's most likely that your middleware simply isn't calling `next()`, which doesn't execute your routes. Additionally, the middleware most likely didn't execute at all when you had your routes before your middleware. These are just my best guesses - I have no way of knowing without seeing the relevant code.

Answer (score 3):

Routes and middleware should be placed in the order that you want them to be matched against the route and then to execute (if they match the incoming route).  There is no absolute answer to which comes first as it really depends upon what you're trying to do.  For example, you would put `app.use(express.json())` before any route that wants to use a JSON formatted body.  But, you would put the login page route handler BEFORE any middleware that checks to see if the user is authenticated (so that it can run for users that aren't yet authenticated).

If your code stops working when you put the middleware first, then there is probably something wrong with the implementation of the middleware.  We can only help with that specific issue if you show us the actual code for that middleware.  Perhaps you aren't calling `next()` to continue routing or you're sending a response in the middleware or there's a coding error in the middleware.

Comment: Thanks … I get what u are saying mostly … but why not just put app.use(express.json)at the very top in all cases.  Seems like express should auto detect json and populate req.body and this should not be needed at all.  It’s like saying if you see JSON it exists. The whole framework confuses me.

Comment: @favor - Generally, you would put `app.use(express.json())` near the top of the list.  It need not be confusing.  You place both middleware and routes in the order you want them to execute.  Sometimes, the order is irrelevant.  Like it doesn't matter what order you put `app.get("/about", handleAbout)` and `app.get("/contact", handleContact)` because they don't overlap in any way.  But, it does matter what order you put `app.use(redirectIfNotLoggedIn)` and `app.get("/login", showLoginPage)` because you have to allow the login page to show, even when they aren't logged in.